# how to properly import a module which need another module to run？

Tags: python

I met an import error called `no module named XX.`
my project file is organized as follows:

```
-------A.py
          |
          B-----__init__.py        wrote: from .C import C
                        |
                        C.py
                        |​
                        D -----__init__.py           wrote: from .E import E
                                         |
                                         E.py
```

In A.py, I need to import class C from C.py. but class C needs to use class E(in E.py)to run

In A.py, I wrote `import B.C`

In C.py, I wrote `import D.E`

when I run the test in A.py, it gives the error:    `No module named 'D'`
But if I test C.py, there is no problem at all.

Can anyone tell me why and how to fix it?

Comment: try `import B.D.E`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to run `A.py`, it fails because the Python interpreter (the program that runs your Python script) cannot find the `D` package.

When you run `C.py`, however, the interpreter *does* find the `D` package. This is because the script you are running (`C.py`) is located in the *same directory/folder* as the `D` package.

Detailed explanation found in the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

> When a module named `spam` is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named `spam.py` in a list of directories given by the variable `sys.path`. `sys.path` is initialized from these locations:
>
> - **The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).**
> - PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - The installation-dependent default (by convention including a site-packages directory, handled by the site module).

A quick fix would be to use a relative import in `C.py`:

```
from .D import E
```